# How to merge from branch to branch and back again (bidirectional merging) in SVN?

Tags: svn, version-control

Using the svnmerge.py tool it is possible to merge between branches, up and down.  It is hard to find the details for doing this.  Hopefully, v1.5 will have a neat method for doing this without using svnmerge.py - details requested!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're asking about 1.5 merge tracking.  Here's a quick overview for doing merges to/from trunk (or another branch): http://blog.red-bean.com/sussman/?p=92

Answer (score 0):

With svnmerge.py, you initialize both branches (when going in one direction, you only need to initialize one of the branches).  Then merge using the -b (For bidirectional flag).  Here is a summary starting from branch one to branch two.  $REPO is the protocol and path to your repository.

> svn copy $REPO/branches/one $REPO/branches/two \
>   -m "Creating branch two from branch one."
>   svn checkout branches/one one
>   svn checkout branches/two two
>
> cd one
>   svnmerge init ../two
>   cd ../two
>   svnmerge init ../one

You may now edit both branches.  Changes from one to two can be merged by:

> cd two
>   svnmerge merge -b -S one
>   svn commit -F svnmerge-commit-message.txt

Conversely, changes from two to one can be merge by:

> cd one
>   svnmerge merge -b -S two
>   svn commit -F svnmerge-commit-message.txt

Be sure to note the -b flag!